# VHDL 4 Bit Comperator using 2 Bit Comperator

Tags: vhdl

I'm having troubles  to create a 4-Bit Comparator using 2-Bit `greater than  Comparator` and 2-bit `equality Comparator`.

**greater than Comparator**

```
entity bit2com is                
    Port ( a,b: in  STD_LOGIC_vector(1 downto 0);
           y : out  STD_LOGIC);
end bit2com;

architecture Behavioral of bit2com is

signal p0,p1,p2:std_logic;

begin

p0  <= a(1) and not b(1);
p1  <= a(0) and a(1) and not b(0);
p2<=a(0) and not b(0) and not b(1);
y <= p0 or p1 or p2;

end Behavioral;
```

---

**equality Comparator**

```
entity comaeqb is

    Port ( a,b: in  STD_LOGIC_vector(1 downto 0);
           y : out  STD_LOGIC);
end comaeqb;

architecture Behavioral of comaeqb is

signal p0,p1,p2,p3:std_logic;
begin

p0  <= a(0) and a(1) and b(0) and b(1);
p1  <= a(0) and not a(1) and b(0) and not b(1);

p2<=not a(0) and not a(1) and not b(0) and not b(1);
p3<=not a(0) and a(1) and not b(0) and b(1);
y <= p0 or p1 or p2 or p3;
```

How can I use this to make a 4 bit greater than Comparator?

Comment: Declare A,B as numeric_std.[un]signed, and write `Y <= '1' when A > B else '0';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you tried to create 4-bit comparator from 2-bit comparators (`>` and `=`). But I think there are 2 answers for you question:

1. If you just want to create 4-bit comparator without any comparator (independent), please declare `A and B` as `signed` or `unsigned` to compare (you can convert to this type if you use `std_logic_vector`). There are two libraries to use: `arith` and `numeric_std` (just use one of them, both is violated).
2. If you have to use 2 bit comparators. Use this way:

Propose `A = [A3 A2 A1 A0]` and `B = [B3 B2 B1 B0]`. Run two steps:

**Step 1** compare two MSB with yours comparators:

```
if [A3 A2] > [B3 B2] then
  A_greater_than_B <= '1';
elsif [A3 A2] < [B3 B2] then
  A_greater_than_B <= '0';
else -- [A3 A2] = [B3 B2]
-- next step >>>
end if;
```

**Step 2** compare two LSBs with yours comparators with similar method with **Step 1**. This branch is occurred when `[A3 A2] =[ B3  B2]`. Result of **step 2** is result of 4-bit comparator. For example, if `[A1 A0] = [B1 B0]` then `A = B`.